# How to register different implementations of an interface in a tsyringe container based on a given parameter

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, tsyringe

I am trying to find an elegant way to inject an Interface into the [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe) container based on a given value. (string/enum/Symbol)

This is how I would do it with a `switch..case` clause:

```
interface IColor{
  someMethod():void;
  readonly someInfo:any;
}

class Blue implements IColor{
  constructor() {
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log('I am blue');
  }
}
class Red implements IColor{
  constructor() {
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log('I am red');
  }
}
@injectable()
class SurfaceService{
  constructor(@inject('IColor')readonly color:IColor) {
  }
}

// main
import {container} from "tsyringe";
const mainFunction = (someData:{colorinfo:string}) =>{

  switch (someData.colorinfo){
    case 'RED':
      container.register("IColor", {useClass: Red});
      break;

    case 'Blue':
      container.register("IColor", {useClass: Blue});
      break;
  }

  const service = container.resolve(SurfaceService); 
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that it is not very elegant and it requires to import all possible implementation even though, only one is needed at runtime.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/molszanski/8ebf5979fc567381e6ef27f79b3bf072) which was part of my research of DI solutions.

Apparently one has to use [`predicateawareclassfactory`](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#predicateawareclassfactory). But I've found that a simpler version, that worked just fine `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```js
container.register(Tokens.logger, {
  useFactory: () => {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? container.resolve(PinoLogger)
      : container.resolve(ConsoleLogger)
  },
})
```

Comment: yea thats works, but you are right thats not so nice.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: author here

Here is a solution, but in different DI framework.

I think this is the only DI solution that supports async lazy imports to avoid importing things you don't need at runtime. Any other DI system would have to support `async`. To my best knowledge, no other does at the time of writing. I've checked around 30.

Interactive working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ngyhjt?file=src/_0.business-logic.ts)

[image: Di code example]

```js
  // Business logic
  interface IColor {
    someMethod(): void
    // readonly someInfo:any;
  }

  export class Blue implements IColor {
    constructor() {}
    someMethod() {
      console.log("I am blue")
    }
  }
  export class Red implements IColor {
    constructor() {}
    someMethod() {
      console.log("I am red")
    }
  }
  export class SurfaceService {
    constructor(readonly color: IColor) {}
  }


  // main
  export const container = createContainer()
    .add(() => ({
      blue: async () => {
        const { Blue } = await import("./_0.business-logic")
        return new Blue()
      },
      red: async () => {
        const { Red } = await import("./_0.business-logic")
        return new Red()
      },
    }))
    .add((ctx) => ({
      surfaceService: async () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (process?.env?.NODE_ENV === "production") {
          return await ctx.blue
        } else {
          return await ctx.red
        }
      },
      getCustomColor: () => async (someData: { colorInfo: string }) => {
        if (someData.colorInfo === "RED") {
          return await ctx.red
        }
        return await ctx.blue
      },
    }))

  // usage
  const colorByEnv = await container.items.surfaceService // Blue or Red
  const red = await container.items.getCustomColor({ colorInfo: "RED" })
```

Comment: You can also do conditional registering and other tricks with `iti`. I've selected what looks to me as two of the most straightforward approaches. I think I could write 4-5 solutions for your problem, but it really depends on what would be the simplest code for your codebase and your project.

Comment: I am wondering if there is something similar than for tsyringe. I am not sure how to overcome the "import issue" but at least register the dependencies for a given symbol or string which is then provided when resolving

Comment: It is possible, but I hate how it works. Posting a demo from my research in another thread